# Updating matomo customvariables via a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, matomo

I have a dockerfile in which pulls in matomo and makes a copy of my config file,

```
FROM matomo:3.14.1

COPY config/config.php /var/www/html/config/config.php

RUN ./console customvariables:set-max-custom-variables 10
```

However I cannot seem to successfully update the custom variables, I can run the docker build without the RUN and see the ./console command within the /var/www/html location, therefore I cant quite understand why it would not then just execute this command also? Im I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image's Dockerfile [declares a VOLUME for the `/var/www/html` directory](https://github.com/matomo-org/docker/blob/63bc1cfa0361154750ab9d6aa9f75cb3a11474e8/apache/Dockerfile#L107) so derived images can't ever change the content of that directory.  You'll need to use a `docker run -v` option or Compose `volumes:` to inject your config file; you can do this without creating a custom image.

```sh
docker run \
  -v $PWD/config/config.php:/var/www/html/config/config.php \
  ... --other-docker-options ... \
  mamoto:3.14.1
```

Comment: Hello, sorry Im a bit unfamiliar with docker, can this be done within the pre-existing docker file and if so how? what would it look like?